# Using CSS, how can I control the line-height for master headline?

Tags: html, css

How can I control the size of the spacing between my h1 and h2 without using 'line-height' in CSS? It needs to be applied to my H1 master that will be used across the entire website, so for example, if a page has a h1 that runs over 2 or 3 lines, I can't have the line-height set to 0px because it won't flow over numerous lines.

My current CSS is:

```
h1 { /** Headlines **/
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 100px;
}

h2 { /** Standfirst **/
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 600;
}
```

I need to reduce the space between H1 and H2 because the current gap is massive and unsightly. Thanks

----EDIT!----
Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Please see this Fiddle - The first example shows the leading that I want from H1.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwfbbs1u/

On the short headline version, it looks exactly how I want it.

On the second version, that format is destroyed because the line-height is set to '0'.

The goal is to be able to have that nice, tight spacing from the first example on the second example as well, thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you not wish to use line-height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use negative margin property

```
 h1 { margin-bottom :-100px}
```

**edit :**

this will probably solve your problem , but the best solution would be analyzing why you have the spacing to begin with, and avoid this to happen (or reduce it to your taste)

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. You should never need to use a negative margin.  Use line-height instead.

Comment: I agree this isn't best practice; but it's what the OP has asked; moreover without a fiddle or pen it's impossible to know what's best...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS `margin` property of the HTML elements (e.g. h1, h2) in order to achieve the desirable effect, e.g: `h1{margin-bottom:0;}`, `h2{margin-top:0;}`. Property value can be 0, positive or negative number with unit added, like `10px, -10pt, 2em`. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

How about `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`? Change the 0px to your liking. The number can be negative.

```
h1 { /** Headlines **/
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2 { /** Standfirst **/
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cL310qnq/

Comment: This seems to solve my issue. I am fairly new to HTML/CSS - is this a standard way of solving this problem, or is it a hack? Thanks

Comment: That's generally how you change the distance between objects like this. When you inspect the h1 element (for instance), you can see it has a 67 pixel margin. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/PDSQji9.png - When you want to decrease the margin (so the object below gets closer), you simply change the `margin-bottom` property to something smaller. Like this, I changed it to 25px instead of the standard 67px: http://i.imgur.com/mZFEq3a.png - Please mark my answer as correct if I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using line-height. Manipulating the layout with other attributes will be rigging it for a short product lifespan.

```css
h1 { /** Headlines **/
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 100px;
line-height:100px
}

h2 { /** Standfirst **/
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
line-height:30px;
font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</h2>
```

Comment: I agree with @josephcasey here, though I would suggest using relative line-height, and not pixels. 'line-height: 1;' is what you want.

Comment: @SeanStopnik ideally, he would be using a preprocessor with rem/em font sizes, in my opinion.

Comment: Agree... Though not a fan of ems personally. I personally prefer pixels for text size, since I like to know exactly how it'll render, but line-height should always be relative to the text size regardless of what units you use. Unless of course you are doing so vertical centering thing in a button or something like that. But ya... I think we are basically on the same page here.